# React on page refresh Nothing was returned from render Error

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

i don't know why but when i refresh the page i'm getting this error:
but when i try to go same page from menu with react-router link everything work well

```
(AComponent)... Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:11
   8 | 
   9 | 
  10 | const target = document.querySelector('#root')
> 11 | render(
  12 |   <Provider store={store}>
  13 |     <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  14 |       <div className="row">
```

here is where this error showing.

```
import React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import store, { history } from './store'
import App from './containers/app'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div className="row">
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: do you have element `#root` somewhere in the DOM?

Comment: in my public/index.html i have it yes  <div id="root"></div>

Answer (score 1):

`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ? That's how you would attach your React project to the element.

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div className="row">
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: on the react documentation they use, `document.getElementById`. did you try that?

Comment: yep i already tried it too : const target = document.getElementById('root')

Comment: update your code in the question with the new version please

Comment: there is no have some new version. I'm not understand where the problem

Comment: just copy paste the code with React.DOM inside the question please

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @user3348410 how do you import your `js` file ?

Comment: which javascript file?

Comment: this `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for help. I figure out with this problem. 
It's problem not related with react-router or anything else it's because on some component state was be null where i render component conditionally with state